# how to fix robots.txt not found 404 error. when website is indexed in google

Tags: robots.txt

Dear friends, when I enter example.com/robots.txt at the end of my site, I get a 404 Google error.

But when I enter as example.com/en/robots.txt It enters my site and gives a 404 error. "The page was not found."

My site content is on Google Index. Do I have a new problem or not?

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You'll have to put your robots.txt where it's accessible by the crawlers. Seems like that is not the case from the error messages.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.